# Long range RFID for tracking stationary object

Tags: rf, antenna, rfid

I am totally new to the field of RFID, I want to make a device that can track RFID passive antenna in at least 10m radius and if possible 20m radius (just by latency know how far away from the antenna you are then based on the devices movement and the change in latency a chip can calculate the antennas position)

is this possible and if it is what should look into?

bonus question would it be possible to make it directional so it only beamed for antennas in like and 180-degree cone?

for those who might wonder what it is for, my idea is that people just can put small RFID sticker antenna on the underside of the disc in disc golf, which doesn't affect the flight of the disc but then you can fast find disc which is lost rough.

Comment: Most Induction loops in stores on either side of equal or greater diameter than the gap to the RFID for a good reason.  (fundamentals on loop H field) Reconsider your geometry specs with antenna gain.  How much gain do you need in the antenna?

Comment: It isn't going to work. Forget it.

Comment: @Andyaka maybe explain? how would it not be possible? couldn't I just scale up the size of the antenna and give the trandsender more gain? e.g. saw this youtube vid where they had 20m+ of rfid range:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UXUZwOD0wxs&ab_channel=EllenD

Comment: A passive disc cannot be detected at that range. Simple. Law of physics etc..

Comment: the only info i need is just the range from the device to the rfid, I don't really need it to store any information, so in theory I could probs just use an antenna which then sends back the signal calculate length based on latency, how would I make such passive device which just rebounds the signal?

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to use RFID systems at UHF frequencies, like the system in the YouTube video you've shown in the previous comments. It's possible to reach those 20m of range, but more realistically UHF RFID applications get between 10-15m of real range.

There are two options to determine the direction:

1. You need a highly directional antenna and use it to scan, mechanically or electronically, over the 180º you want.
2. Instead of a scanning antenna you can also use two receiving antennas with a separation of approximately half a wavelength (~173 mm @ 868 MHz) and you can then calculate the angle of arrival (AoA) of the reflected signal from the tag and with that determine the direction of the tag. The more antennas you use in reception the better algorithm of AoA you can implement.

To estimate the distance you can use the RSSI, essentially the signal strength from the reflected signal. This is not very accurate, but will give you a decent indication of the distance to the target.

By having an approximate direction and distance should be easier to locate the lost disk.

Keep in mind the following about RFID systems, so that you're sure to be looking at the correct information:
RFID systems operate at different frequencies and depending on the frequency they use different transmission mechanisms. There are RFID systems working at 125 kHz (LF), 13.6 MHz (HF) and 860-960 MHz (UHF). The first you find in anti-theft systems, the second you'll find in card systems, like access cards, the last one you find in applications like asset tracking/logistics and parking lots, among other applications.

The systems at LF and HF use induction as the communication interface mechanism. Therefore the communication ranges are fairly small and usually the range is directly tied to the size of the coils (it's possible to increase the range if you chose resonant inductive coupling mechanisms).

The systems at UHF operate differently, using radio frequency waves, and can usually allow a larger communication distance. Commercial UHF RFID systems can have ranges up to 20m. These systems, however, are more complex and expensive.